# android NDK fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory #include <stdio.h>

Tags: android, c, qt, android-ndk, c-preprocessor

I am trying to build QPSQL driver for my Qt android project in my Archlinux which is failing constantly

```
configure: error: C preprocessor "/opt/AndroidSDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-cpp" fails sanity check
```

So I tried simple hello World Program :-

```
% /opt/AndroidSDK/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-cpp t.c
# 1 "t.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "t.c"
t.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

This means arm-linux-androideabi-cpp preprocessor is not working , Right ?
But my other Projects from Qt Creator and Android Studio builds and runs fine

What should I do ? I tried updating NDK to 18 which ended up horribly as they replaced gcc with clang. So I have r17b and latest android SDK .

Comment: Why can't you use Clang?

Comment: @DanAlbert I am getting more errors than ever . Also clang binaries are slower than gcc's binaries

Comment: You really need to stick to an old NKD version. I've got stable results with 10 and 11

Comment: @dtech do u mean NDK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't invoke the tools in `$NDK/toolchains` without passing a whole bunch of flags to point them at the sysroot (enabling this sort of use case is an r19 feature).

Use https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain to configure a toolchain for this sort of use.